# Cobol programs to pass parameters to TWS jobs

Tags: cobol, mainframe, workload-scheduler

Would the use of variables be the best method? In the similar way the EQQPIFJC does to manipulate JCL/TWS variables?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main possibilities to pass some variables to a submitted job stream:

1. Replace the value in a variable table, and submit the job stream (occurrence). If you need to submit the same job stream multiple time, this method may be difficult to manage, since you cannot change the variable table value until the job stream has completed.
2. Use a JCL preparation job at the beginning of your job stream and then submit the job stream and use the [JCL Preparation PIFs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSRULV_9.3.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.3/zos/src_pif/eqqn1jclprepx.htm) to specify your variable values or edit the job JCLs.